# How to hash integers within a for loop

Tags: for-loop, hash, integer, sha256

I want to hash a range of integers. How can I define the argument in sha256 as we know it takes just string and buffer?

```
c=list()
import hashlib
   for i in range(0,10):
   d=hashlib.sha256(i).hexdigest()
   c.append(d)
   print(c)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you need an SHA256 of an integer for?

Comment: @martinstoeckli It looks like he's trying to create a hash of a bunch of integers.

Comment: Hash functions operate on bytes. Only you can decide the right way to encode the integer into bytes. One simple way to use `int.to_bytes()`. For example, `d=hashlib.sha256(i.to_bytes(1, 'big', signed=False)).hexdigest()`

Comment: @JamesKPolk why the output of byte([i]) and what you said is different? As i want to hash a range of number between 0-9999 and byte should be <256, so what is your suggestion ?